# Way to exclude a joined relation object from the result set in Propel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, propel

I have 4 tables, that represent a simple survey db setup:

```
table name: (delimited columns)
---------------------------------------------------------------
survey: (id, title)
surveyQuestion: (id, title)
surveyAnswer: (id, surveyQuestionID, title, sortOrder)
surveyToSurveyQuestion: (surveyID, surveyQuestionID, sortOrder)
```

Here is a query I use to pull all of the surveys with all related questions and answers:

```
$query = SurveyQuery::create()
    ->joinWith('SurveyToSurveyQuestion')
    ->useSurveyToSurveyQuestionQuery()
        ->orderBySurveyId()
        ->orderBySortOrder()
        ->joinWith('SurveyQuestion')
        ->useSurveyQuestionQuery()
            ->joinWith('SurveyAnswer')
            ->useSurveyAnswerQuery()
                ->orderBySortOrder()
            ->endUse()
        ->endUse()
    ->endUse();
```

However, many-to-many '`SurveyToSurveyQuestion`' relation gets bloated as I add more surveys, specially if surveys share questions.

**Is there a way to exclude the '`SurveyToSurveyQuestion`' data from the result dataset?**

Edit:

Attaching the db schema.

```
<table name="survey" idMethod="native" phpName="Survey">
    <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="statusID" phpName="StatusID" type="INTEGER" required="true"/>
    <column name="code" phpName="Code" type="VARCHAR" required="true"/>
    <column name="createdDate" phpName="CreatedDate" type="TIMESTAMP" default="0000-00-00 00:00:00"/>
    <index name="INDEX_StatusID">
        <index-column name="statusID"/>
    </index>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="status">
        <reference local="statusID" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <vendor type="mysql">
        <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
    </vendor>
</table>
<table name="surveyQuestion" idMethod="native" phpName="SurveyQuestion">
    <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="surveyQuestionTypeID" phpName="SurveyQuestionTypeID" type="INTEGER" required="true"/>
    <column name="code" phpName="Code" type="VARCHAR" required="true"/>
    <index name="INDEX_SurveyQuestionTypeID">
        <index-column name="surveyQuestionTypeID"/>
    </index>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="surveyQuestionType">
        <reference local="surveyQuestionTypeID" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <vendor type="mysql">
        <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
    </vendor>
</table>
<table name="surveyQuestionType" idMethod="native" phpName="SurveyQuestionType">
    <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="title" phpName="Title" type="VARCHAR" required="true"/>
    <vendor type="mysql">
        <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
    </vendor>
</table>
<table name="surveyAnswer" idMethod="native" phpName="SurveyAnswer">
    <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="surveyQuestionID" phpName="SurveyQuestionID" type="INTEGER" required="true"/>
    <column name="code" phpName="Code" type="VARCHAR" required="true"/>
    <column name="sortOrder" phpName="SortOrder" type="INTEGER"/>
    <index name="INDEX_SurveyQuestionID">
        <index-column name="surveyQuestionID"/>
    </index>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="surveyQuestion">
        <reference local="surveyQuestionID" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <vendor type="mysql">
        <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
    </vendor>
</table>
<table name="surveyToSurveyQuestion" idMethod="native" phpName="SurveyToSurveyQuestion">
    <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="surveyID" phpName="SurveyID" type="INTEGER" required="true"/>
    <column name="surveyQuestionID" phpName="SurveyQuestionID" type="INTEGER" required="true"/>
    <column name="sortOrder" phpName="SortOrder" type="INTEGER"/>
    <index name="INDEX_SurveyID">
        <index-column name="surveyID"/>
    </index>
    <index name="INDEX_SurveyQuestionID">
        <index-column name="surveyQuestionID"/>
    </index>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="survey">
        <reference local="surveyID" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="surveyQuestion">
        <reference local="surveyQuestionID" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <vendor type="mysql">
        <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
    </vendor>
</table>
```

**EDIT:** Using `join` in place of `joinWith` did the job for me. Thanks @kripple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `->joinwith()` to use `->useSurveyToSurveyQuestion()`

You can exclude the join calls resulting in the joined objects not being there.

Additionally, I would have methods on each survey that got their respective questions and answers

```
$surveys = SurveyQuery::create()->filterByXXX()->find()
foreach($survey as $s){
  //Grab each survey's respective data
  $QandA = $s->getQuestionsAndAnswers();
  // do something with the data.
  $otherClass->doStuffWithData($QandA);
}
```

Doing so will increase trips to the DB no doubt, but I think the overall efficiency will be much better.

Comment: Good point about skipping the `joinwith()`, +1 for that. However, my query fails if I remove the `->joinWith('SurveyToSurveyQuestion')` line. Any other ideas?

Comment: Query fails with no results? Or some sort of php error?

Comment: Error is `Unknown column "SurveyId" on model, alias or table "Survey"`

Comment: My suspicion is that it has something to do with the many-to-many relation of the `surveyToSurveyQuestion` table, but I am not sure what exactly.

Comment: Do you have the relations properly setup in the schema? can you link me the schema?

Comment: ` ->orderBySurveyId()` needs to be the same as the foriegn key references ` ->orderBySurveyID()`

Comment: Wouldn't that be an issue no matter with or without `->joinWith()`?

Comment: `joinWith()` method `Adds a JOIN clause to the query and hydrates the related objects`, try to use just `join()`.

Comment: @kripple: Just run into this again and noticed your last comment. Thanks!